# Avoid Circular Reference in Symfony DI

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Is there any design pattern to solve the circular reference issue? that is not injecting the service container!

For example:

- A depends on C, C depends on B and B depends on A.

Thanks.

Comment: Nope except for avoiding these.

Comment: This really can only be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend having a look at the [Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Also see [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and a helpful article about it on tutsplus ([DIP](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-4-the-dependency-inversion-principle--net-36872))

One good way to eliminate circular dependencies.